# Connecting 3 12v batteries for a 24v system

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, solar-cell

I currently have two 100AH 12v batteries connected to two 240 watt solar panels, I'm planning to buy an additional battery, how do I connect it to the other two?

Comment: You put it in storage until you can afford a fourth.

Comment: so I have to have two batteries? man that sucks!

Comment: buy a 24V battery instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Why not? There are 3 ways you could hook up the extra battery - in series with the first two, in parallel with both of them, or in parallel with one existing battery. Each has its problems:-

1. In series you will have 36V total - probably too much for the panels
   and charge controller.
2. 12V In parallel with 24V the voltages don't match - so expect lots of sparks and blown up batteries!
3. In parallel with one 12V battery the voltages match - but charging current will split between them and the other existing battery will get overcharged/discharged because it only has half the capacity.

You should buy *two* additional batteries and wire them in series, then you will have enough voltage to put them in parallel with the original 24V battery. This will also give you two battery banks which can be isolated from each other if you need to work on one bank or use it for something else.

When wiring batteries in series, try to use identical batteries which are the same age and condition. Buying a 'spare' battery to replace one that might die is probably not worthwhile.

Comment: Upvote.  I agree with all this.  However, the OP says there are already three batteries.  And like you say in this answer the third should not be connected to the system.  So if the OP is not going to buy a fourth battery, I highly suggest that the third battery be kept charged until such a time as it is going to be used.

Comment: I would add that this question and your answer also apply to trying to pull 12 volts from one side of a series/parallel 24V bank of 4 batteries.  It results in a similar imbalance, but in the other direction.  Better is to get a 24V to 12V converter and a barrier strip to make 12 Volts available from the system.

Comment: Excuse one question, please:  I have a pre-existing third battery like this and have wondered about using a charge controller between the new 4 battery 24v solar power system and the 12v battery.  I use a plug-in trickle charger at this point, and have done so for a long time.  It runs multiple 10 Watt PIR lights for safety, distributed throughout the living space for a disabled person.  It works fine but it would be nice if it could be charged from the new solar power system without running it from the part-time inverter.

Comment: Get a battery charger that works from 24V, or use a small inverter to power a mains charger. http://www.powerstream.com/DC-input-chargers.htm